# Android - Check Slow Network Connection

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, connection, wifi

I have a function that redirects to the error page if the internet connection is bad but it is not working good.

I can get the bandwidth but i doubt if it is correct. Bandwidth does not drop even when wifi signal is 1. Where is the problem or do you have a better idea?

```
private fun connectionCheck(){
        val progressDialog: AlertDialog = getDialogProgressBar().create()
        val startTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
        var endTime: Long
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val POOR_BANDWIDTH = 150
        val AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH = 400
        val GOOD_BANDWIDTH = 800

        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://google.com")
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                val timeTakenMills = floor((endTime - startTime).toDouble())
                val timeTakenSecs = timeTakenMills / 1000
                val kilobytePerSec = (1024 / timeTakenSecs).toInt()
                if (kilobytePerSec <= POOR_BANDWIDTH) {
                    progressDialog.show()
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post{
                        Toast.makeText(context,"$kilobytePerSec : Bad connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed(
                            {
                                progressDialog.dismiss()
                                replaceFragment(ErrorFragment())
                            }, 2000)
                    }

                } else if (kilobytePerSec <=AVERAGE_BANDWIDTH) {
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post{
                        Toast.makeText(context,"$kilobytePerSec : Average connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post{
                        Toast.makeText(context,"$kilobytePerSec : Good connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

I read the bandwidth values but couldn't find anything useful.